# Its possible to change the hex code on dump?

Tags: c++, hex, dump, ollydbg

So, I have one .exe file and every time I dump it on ollydbg, it returns the same hex code.

And I do a lot of modifications in the source, but the hex values is still the same!

Is there a way to change this?

Comment: Huh? What "hex code" are you talking about?

Comment: Its like this: 0x8A 0x5C 0x24 0x17 0x3A 0x9D 0x39 0x0E 0x00 0x00 0x8A 0x4C 0x24 01x6 0x3A 0x8D 0x3A 0x0E 0x00 0x00

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the old MS-DOS header at the beginning of every PE file. This is an obsolete header followed by a tiny DOS program that will output an error message saying that Windows is required to run the program. Windows skips over these ancient headers.

There's some documentation [here](http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDevPE.html). They are called the "IMAGE_DOS_HEADER" and the "STUB program".